# GET request always defaults to /(?:)/i - how can i make it 'undefined'?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, get, xregexp

If i use RegExp then my Search Widget page always gets:
/(?:)/i

And thus always loads with a list of results. I dont want this this to happen. I just want my page to load, then a user fills out the search box and it then does the GET request.

```
app.get("/la_widget", function(req, res) {

  var test = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');
  console.log(test);

  Restaurant.find({
      LocalAuthorityName: test
    },
    null,
    {
      limit: 50
    },
    function(err, foundAuthority) {
      if (foundAuthority) {
        res.render("la_widget", {foundAuthority})
    } else {
      res.render("la_widget", "No local authority matching that input was found.");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it's not wise to allow user input to define regex expressions [*](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for the comment, id like to find outmore about the best way to do this. Would you have an example or some extra info please? When i change the DB or add extra documents to my MongoDb I often get this issue reoccurring, of auto searches firing off, before ive filled in the search box and hit 'search' button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the `req.query.search` string is defined (thuthey) before setting the search query.

```
const test = (req.query.search) 
  ? new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
  : undefined
```

This uses a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator which equates to:

```
let test
if (req.query.search) {
   test = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
}
else {
   test = undefined
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt - thanks so much, that worked! I'm really new to programming so ill research how this fixed it. Many thanks!

Comment: This is called a [ternery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) statement, basically a different way to write if/then/else.

Comment: I use it for variable assignment so the variable stays outside the `if` statements scope.

Comment: I was looking to refine my code to search 2 or 3 fields in my database, rather than just one. So right now it just checks 
 `Restaurant.find({
      LocalAuthorityName: test
    },`

But id like it to check an array of fields. 

I tried:
Restaurant.find({
$or:[{
      AddressLine3: test3
    },
    {
      AddressLine4: test4
    }]},

But this just gave me my original problem of auto executing the search on page load, instead of having a blank search box ready for a new search. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure sorry, probably detail that in a new question.

Comment: yes good idea, my question wasnt posed very well. I've written a fuller and more logical question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076746/get-request-always-defaults-to-i-how-can-i-make-it-undefined-second
Thanks for all your help so far!