# GET request always defaults to /(?:)/i - how can i make it 'undefined'? - Second question on this topic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, get, xregexp

I got some great help on here to fix my GET request always defaulting to /(?:)/i. I can now set my GET to undefined.

However, this only works when searching for one field 'BusinessName' in my DB.
My question is, how do i search multiple fields, so 'BusinessName' and also 'Address'.
Here is the code as it is, working when it searches just one field:

```
app.get("/widget", function(req, res) {


  // This  returns just one restaurant and doesnt do partial string matching
  /* let test = req.query.search */

  // This returns up to 200 results that partially match the search term
  /*  let test = new RegExp (req.query.search, 'i'); */

  // This sets the query to undefined, to start with
    const test = (req.query.search)
    ? new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
    : undefined

  Restaurant.find({
    BusinessName: test
  }, null, {
    limit: 200
  }, function(err, foundRestaurant) {
    console.log(test);

    if (foundRestaurant) {

      /* res.send(foundRestaurant) */
      res.render("widget", {
        foundRestaurant
      })
    } else {
      res.render("widget", "No restaurants matching that title was found.");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my broken attempt to get it to work by using fields 'AddressLine3' and 'AddressLine4':

```
app.get("/town_widget", function(req, res) {

  const test3 = (req.query.search)
  ? new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
  : undefined

  const test4 = (req.query.search)
  ? new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
  : undefined

  Restaurant.find({
$or:[{
      AddressLine3: test3
    },
    {
      AddressLine4: test4
    }]},
    null, {
      limit: 2
    },

    function(err, foundTown) {
      if (foundTown) {
        console.log(foundTown);
        res.render("town_widget", {
          foundTown
        })
      } else {
        res.render("town_widget", "No town or city matching that input was found/no restaurants found in the town specified.");
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you MongoDb? If so add that tag to your question, and look up the `$and` operator.

Comment: Hi O.Jones, the town in my data is sometimes in AddressLine3 and sometimes in AddressLine4. So I used the Or operator. Should I use the And operator? If i use the Or operator,  it forgets the query is undefined to begin with and always gives a search when I load the page, before I enter a search query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.Jones thanks for your help. I actually found what I was doing wrong, AddressLine4 doesn't exist in my DB and so including it in my mongo request resulted in the error - I did have AddressLine4 at one point but now I don't. All works great now with the OR operator, cheers